# |x²-2x| + |x-4| > |x²-3x+4| , How do I solve for all real x?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How do I solve this for all real x?

|x²-2x| + |x-4| > |x²-3x+4|

Looking at the question it is clear that it states |a| + |b| > |a-b|. How to proceed?

Comment: Do the usual testing of cases for the signs of $a,b$ in your last line.  That will tell you when it is true.  Use that knowledge to solve the problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan Like ...do I take a> 0, b>0 in 1st case, then a<0 and b> 0 in 2nd case and so forth?

Comment: That is right.  You should find two combinations that make the inequality true and two that make it false.

Comment: The non-strict inequality is always true, by the triangle inequality: $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$, with $a = x^2 - 2x$ and $b = -(x - 4)$. Strict inequality from the triangle inequality occurs when $a$ and $b$ have different signs (i.e. one is positive and one is negative).

Comment: Hint: you need $ab\geqslant0$

Comment: @Macavity yes I tried to get there but couldn't figure out how

Comment: Consider just two cases, when $a,b$ have same sign and different ones. You have to eliminate only the equality case to get strict inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that by the triangle inequality
$$|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$$ and the equality occurs for $ab\geq0.$

Now, we have $$|x^2-2x|+|x-4|=|x^2-2x|+|4-x|\geq|x^2-3x+4|.$$

Id est, our inequality is equivalent to   $$(x^2-2x)(4-x)<0$$ or
$$x(x-2)(x-4)>0,$$ which by the intervals method gives $$(4,+\infty)\cup(0,2).$$

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $x^2-3x+4$ is always positive because discriminant $D=(-3)^2-4\times4<0$.

**Case 1:** $x\in(-\infty, 0]$

In this range: $|x^2-2x|=x^2-2x$, $|x-4|=-(x-4)$ and the inequality becomes:

$$x^2-2x-(x-4)>x^2-3x+4$$

$$x^2-3x+4>x^2-3x+4$$

...which is never true. So the ineqality has no solution in the given range.

**Case 2:** $x\in(0, 2]$

In this range: $|x^2-2x|=-(x^2-2x)$, $|x-4|=-(x-4)$ and the inequality becomes:

$$-(x^2-2x)-(x-4)>x^2-3x+4$$

$$-x^2+x+4 > x^2-3x+4$$

$$0 > 2x^2-4x$$

$$0 > x^2-2x=x(x-2)$$

...and this is obviously true for $x\in(0,2)$. Combined with the initial condition that $x\in(0,2]$ this gives one part of the solution: $x\in(0,2)$

**Case 3:** $x\in(2, 4]$

In this range: $|x^2-2x|=x^2-2x$, $|x-4|=-(x-4)$ and the inequality becomes:

$$x^2-2x-(x-4)>x^2-3x+4$$

$$x^2-3x+4>x^2-3x+4$$

...which is never true.

**Case 4:** $x\in(4, +\infty)$

In this range: $|x^2-2x|=x^2-2x$, $|x-4|=x-4$ and the inequality becomes:

$$x^2-2x+x-4>x^2-3x+4$$

$$-x-4>-3x+4$$

$$2x-8>0$$

$$x>4$$

So all values of $x$ in the given range are also solutions to the inequality.

If you summarize all four cases you get the final result:

$$\boxed{x\in(0,2)\cup(4,+\infty)}\tag{1}$$

The solution can be confirmed by looking at the plot of the function:

$$f(x)=|x^2-2x| + |x-4| - |x^2-3x+4|$$

[image]

...which is positive for values of $x$ defined by (1).

Comment: Downvoting without a comment? Eh... I would kindly ask a guy who downvoted the correct answer to explain the reasoning behind it. I am ready to learn.

Comment: It is a complete waste not to use the hint $|a|+|b|>|a-b|$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you please show me how this leads to $\boxed{x\in(0,2)\cup(4,+\infty)}\tag{1}$. And why did you delete your answer? Calling a correct answer a "compelte waste" is also very pretentious.